# How can I call IEnumerator when a boolean is true?

Tags: c#, function, unity-game-engine, ienumerator

I'm using the IEnumerator function and have had some issues with my if statement working:

```
IEnumerator Spawning()
    {
        Debug.Log("Spawning being called...");
        if (GameObject.Find("FPSController").GetComponent<BoxCollide>().hitTrigger == true)
        {
            Debug.Log("CUSTOMER SHOULD SPAWN!");
            while (countStop == false) {

                yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
                Debug.Log("Fisher Spawned!");
                counter++;
                spawnNewCharacter.SpawnCharacter();

                if (counter >= 3){
                    countStop = true;
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

After some debugging, it turns out that my if statement actually works. This issue is actually the `IEnumerator` function being called as soon as I run my game. I need a way to call this `IEnumerator` function only when my `hitTrigger == true`, but I can't seem to get anything to work.

I've tried this on top of the `IEnumerator` function:

```
void Update()
    {
        if (GameObject.Find("FPSController").GetComponent<BoxCollide>().hitTrigger == true)
        {
            Debug.Log("Spawning now...");
            StartCoroutine(Spawning());
        }
    }
```

But still can't even get any of the `Debug.Log`'s to come through. Would appreciate some help on this!

Comment: There's no question here to answer; this isn't a service for debugging your buggy code for you. Do you have a *specific* question that has an answer?

Comment: I will note that doing a comparison against true or false is a sure sign of beginner code.  Never say `if (x == true)`; that looks amateurish. You're asking the question "is it true that x is true?" instead of asking "is X true?"  Just say `if(x)`.  And never say `while (x == false)`.  Say `while (!x)`.

Comment: Hi @EricLippert, thanks for that tip. I'm just trying to figure out how I can call the IEnumrator function when hitTrigger turns true in my other script.

Comment: Well, what does `StartCoroutine` do?  Does it run the coroutine to the first yield, or does it start the coroutine suspended, and the coroutine has to be resumed?  (Not a rhetorical question; I genuinely do not know.)

Comment: @EricLippert https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html StartCoroutine is a Unity function. It's a general purpose synchronous task scheduler (Unity does not handle multithreading well).

Comment: @toadflax write your if statements the way you want, there is nothing wrong with saying `if(x == true)`  "looks amateurish" isn't constructive and if it helps you read  and understand what you are trying to do, then that is all that matters.

Comment: @toadflax can you include your other script so we can see how you are setting hitTrigger to true/false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Side Information

**Find() and GetComponent()**

You don't want to use GameObject.Find(...) in the Update method, as it's an expensive call. The Update method is called each frame, so you'd call GameObject.Find(...) 60 times in 1 second at 60fps.
So when you use GetComponent() or Find() you want to save a reference to these objects like shown in the snippets below.

Better locations to use methods like GetComponent() or GameObject.Find() are the [Awake()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Awake.html) and [Start()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html) methods.

**Awake**

> Awake is used to initialize any variables or game state before the
>   game starts. Awake is called only once during the lifetime of the
>   script instance. Awake is called after all objects are initialized so
>   you can safely speak to other objects or query them using eg.
>   GameObject.FindWithTag. [...]
>   **Explanation is taken from the linked documentation.**

**Start**

> Start is called on the frame when a script is enabled just before any
>   of the Update methods is called the first time. Like the Awake
>   function, Start is called exactly once in the lifetime of the script.
>   However, Awake is called when the script object is initialised,
>   regardless of whether or not the script is enabled. Start may not be
>   called on the same frame as Awake if the script is not enabled at
>   initialisation time.
>   **Explanation is also taken from the linked documentation**

---

### Possible Solution

Add the first Component (FPSControllerCollission) onto the object that holds your FPSController.
It makes use of unities [OnTriggerEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter.html) & [OnTriggerExit](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerExit.html) methods.

This script is gonna set the IsTriggered bool to **true**, when a trigger entered the space of the box collider.

> Note: A collider acts as a trigger, when the "Is Trigger" checkbox on
>   the component is checked.

You can do similar with [OnCollisionEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html)/Exit to recognize, when a Collider enters the space of the box collider.

> Note that the following is only an example and you'll have to tweak /
>   integrate it into your code

```
  [RequireComponent(typeof(BoxCollider))]
  public class FPSControllerCollission : MonoBehaviour {
    public bool IsTriggered;

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
      this.IsTriggered = true;
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other) {
      //Maybe check the tag/type of the other object here
      this.IsTriggered = false;
    }
  }
```

The following SpawnController class could be integrated in the class you allready have.

```
  public class SpawnController : MonoBehaviour {
    private FPSControllerCollission _fpsControllerCollission;

    private void Awake() {
      this._fpsControllerCollission = FindObjectOfType<FPSControllerCollission>();
    }

    private void Update() {
      if (this._fpsControllerCollission.IsTriggered) {
        StartCoroutine(nameof(Spawning));
      }
    }

    IEnumerator Spawning() {
      Debug.Log("Spawning being called...");
      if (this._fpsControllerCollission == true) {
        Debug.Log("CUSTOMER SHOULD SPAWN!");
        bool countStop = false;
        int counter;
        while (countStop == false) {

          yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
          Debug.Log("Fisher Spawned!");

          counter++;
          spawnNewCharacter.SpawnCharacter();

          if (counter >= 3) {
            countStop = true;
          }

        }
      }
    }
  }
```